# Disable previous dates in rich:calendar

Tags: date, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have the below code xhtml code to disable previous dates in rich calendar using dayDisableFunction attribute.

```
<rich:calendar value="#{accessMBean.scheduleDate}"
                            inputStyle="width:190px" id="scheduledDate"
                            dayDisableFunction="disableBeforeToday" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Please schedule a date" />
```

My java script function looks like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
                        var curDt = new Date();
                    function disableBeforeToday(day) {
                        alert(curDt);
                            return (curDt.getTime() - day.date.getTime() < 0);
                        }
                // ]]>
                </script>
```

However the dates are not getting disabled. I have come across this code over the internet but it does not seem to work. I am stuck to use JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3 and cannot upgrade either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing RichFaces 3 and 4. The function is correct but in RichFaces 3 the attribute is `isDayEnabled`, in RichFaces 4 it was renamed to `dayDisableFunction`. Read the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/calendar.html).

Comment: Thanks Makhiel for the reply. Yes I am now able to disable the previous days post renaming the function. However I am not able to select the current date i.e today as well. Any thing missing in my Javascript function?

Comment: Vinod, use time 0:0:0 instead of curDt.getTime()